Could neutrinos eventually decay? Or are they indefinitely stable?
I was having a discussion with someone here in stack exchange and they came up with the following arguments for the possibility that neutrinos (and other fundamental particles like electrons) may eventually decay. The arguments are:

Why would any massive field be stable? It can not possibly be the ground state.

Based on the fact that neutrinos are massive and that there is no reason to believe from first principles that lepton number is absolutely conserved, it's very unlikely that neutrinos are stable. That's just thermodynamics. Every system will, after a sufficiently long time, assume its lowest energy state. The neutrino isn't it, so why would it be stable?

If you wanted to keep more massive states alive, then you would need a symmetry breaking mechanism (like lepton number conservation, which is black magic as far as I know) that would prevent the transition into the less massive ones

Neutrinos would either decay into particles with a very small mass or into (massless) dark photons


This is the first time I've ever seen a physicist say that fundamental particles will decay just because of the fact that they have mass. Is this correct? When physicists say that fundamental particles will not decay are they exaggerating and actually they will eventually?

Considering that neutrinos are still free streaming through the cosmos from the big bang this seems unlikely, they need to be there for cosmological reasons. If they had already decayed it would leave behind clues. Else their decay rate is unimaginably small.

@Triatticus I am not sure a direct detection of cosmic neutrino decay would be all that simple. Let's assume neutrino masses in the 0.1eV range and the decay leaves us with photons. That puts the remnant radiation into the 12um wavelength band. There is a lot of thermal background in that range. Not sure we could hope to separate the signal from the background. I could be wrong.

It's more that if neutrino species didn't contribute to the matter density then we would have noticed, we set bounds on relic neutrino density and it should match observed cosmological models.

In the Standard Model with massive neutrinos, $ν_2$ and $ν_3$ (the higher mass eigenstates) are theoretically unstable to decay by, e.g., $ν_i \to ν_j + γ$ (where $i,j \in \{1,2,3\}, i>j$), but those decays may be unobservably rare. There is a discussion here, taken from p.104 of Dark Matter and Background Light (2004) by Overduin and Wesson. As far as I know there has been no detection of a neutrino decay in the 20 years since then.
$ν_1$ is stable because a decay has to conserve angular momentum, but there are no lighter particles with half-integer spin. A similar argument can be made for electron stability with electric charge in place of angular momentum. There's no need to invoke lepton number conservation, which is on shakier footing.
If you go beyond the Standard Model then anything is possible. Even the vacuum may be unstable.

but nowadays, are there any "beyond-the-standard-model" model where neutrinos decay? Because I've not even heard about one like that @benrg

@venagaq You can make up whatever you want. Nobody can oppose you if you set the energy scale low enough. We can't do any experiments at those scales. Is that science, though? No, of course not. You are simply filling an empirical vacuum with arbitrary noise.

I'm going to assume you labeled your bullets 1-4. I am also going to ignore the fact that neutrinos are created in flavor eigenstates ($\nu_e, \nu_{\nu}, \nu_{\tau}$), and we're talking about mass eigenstates ($\nu_1, \nu_2, \nu_3$), with the assumption that they are ordered from lightest to heaviest.

A massive field would be stable because it is the ground state, and transitions to a lower energy state (if it exists) are blocked by quantum number conservation.

I don't think thermodynamics is relevant here. A single particle is in a quantum state with 1 micro state (and 1 macrostate), so the entropy is $S = k\log 1 = 0$ (density matrices notwithstanding).
The conservation of lepton number is an experimental observation, so it's made into a "first principle" by observation. You can write a Lagrangian that violates it, at which point it is not a 1st principle. I suppose you could violate flavor and $\nu_2 \rightarrow \nu_1 + X$ where $X$ is unknown and is just there to conserve energy momentum--which is why the neutrino invented in the 1st place. But as of 2024, there is no $X$.

I don't really understand this point. I guess the existence of $X$ in (2) would be the symmetry breaking mechanism, but the point really just sounds like gauge field world salad.

Yes: $M_x \lt m_{\nu_i}$ but there is no $X$ as of yet. I would seriously avoid the use of the phrase "dark photons", not for physics reasons, but sociological. I have never used it in serious physics, but see it bandied about with the "electric universe crowd" and the group that says neutrons are made from bound protons and electrons--crack pot stuff.



I am responsible for the "dark photon" thing. I made a joking comment to his last question and I am afraid that he didn't pick up on the humor. Apologies. What blocks neutrino decay in the current era is lepton number conservation, isn't it? Lepton number can not be conserved if Hawking radiation exists for all I can tell, so either black holes are stable or leptons are not. I would go with the latter. I am not aware that lepton number conservation follows from Poincare symmetry in a fundamental way, either, Maybe I am wrong.

apparently "dark photons" are a thing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_photon , but that is a serious treatment. I've only heard it used in crack-pot contexts. Regarding neutrino decay, what would the final state be? There's no state to block, afaik.

I am aware that there could be a massless field in the dark matter sector, but from an experimental point of view what sounds like hunting of the Snark, right now. I certainly wasn't referring to the crack-pot "free energy folks". What is the ultimately lowest energy state of the universe? If I had a hunch... there is none. I would go with Penrose's CCC and accept that there is no more a "lowest scale" than there is a lowest temperature in thermodynamics. The lower we go, the more tiny higher order effects start to dominate the thermal spectrum.

@FlatterMann I'll ask you about it here as well: Could it be possible that the final decay state or the lowest possible energy state for a hypothetical decaying neutrino could be a massless particle? Or they would only decay into light but still massive particles no matter what? Or both scenarios are possible?

@vengaq What would stop such a decay? Can you name the mechanism? Can you tell me what the mass hierarchy below 1e-30eV is? What experimental technique would you use to determine that hierarchy? The question you are asking here borders on the religious. It can not be answered empirically. Starting from accepted principles all massive fields have to decay... but into what is completely outside of the scope of imaginable research.

@FlatterMann so in principle both scenarios are possible because we cannot rule out anything

@vengaq Science does not deal with the possible. It creates rational explanations of the observed.

@FlatterMann got GUTs?

@JEB Me, personally? No. I am an experimentalist. I am only interested in the data that comes out of LHC and its detectors and a bunch of other (including non-accelerator) experiments. In theory there is no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is. In science we call that difference "empirical data". It's hard to generate and in case of high energy physics it's very expensive. Literally thousands of theorists and experimentalists have dedicated their lives to building and running LHC. If a GUT could solve that, they would have worked in vain.

@FlatterMann I think you mentioned it somewhere but could electrons also possibly decay? Or this is more difficult?

@vengaq What would stop electrons from decaying?

@FlatterMann I think I remember you said something like the symmetry of charge conservation could "save" the electron from decaying?...

@vengaq Are you saying that electron-positron annihilation is not a thing or do you have evidence that there is more negative than positive charge in the universe? Electrons are for sure not stable. Protons may be stable (although I don't know all that many people who actually believe that... having worked next to a group that was building a proton decay experiment).

@FlatterMann but I didn't mean to say that they could decay in electron-positron interactions. I meant whether they can decay "by themselves". If we let an isolated electron be in a vacuum, will there be a moment where it would decay without interacting with anything else?

@vengaq An electron is a quantum of a quantum field. It's not an individual object. At most we can ask if a quantum field is stable. The electron quantum field is the same as the position quantum field. The two can not be separated. That field is not stable. It always annihilates with itself and leaves only an excitation of the electromagnetic field behind. Unless, of course, there is a charge imbalance in the universe. Is there such a charge imbalance that you know of?

@FlatterMann but electrons (or more specifically the electron quantum field) has to encounter and interact with a positron to be annihilated. If we have a cloud of electrons in outer space and they do not encounter any positrons then, shouldn't they be stable?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
